# What is meant by "Are you even up there?"

Tags: meaning, idioms, sentence, cinema

I have seen "The edge of seventeen" movie last Friday.
In that film, Nadine used to say this sentence (See image)

[image: Calling upstairs "Are you even up there?"]

Can any one tell me what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase questions whether the target of the question exists or is located where the speaker assumes.  Thus, if playing hide-and-go-seek where one child hides and ther other tries to find him or her, the seeker may think the hider is in a closet, but cannot open the closet door.  In frustration, the seeker may ask, "Are you even in there?" questioning his or her belief that the hider is inside.

The question takes on especial significance in religious belief as God rarely intervenes directly in a person's life.  Without that ready, first-hand proof of divine existence, and in a situation where the supplicant is frustrated or desparate for assistance, the supplicant may ask, "Are you even up there?" questioning the existence of God and, thereby, questioning their own faith.